# How can I get static role from access token in loopback.io?

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I want to restrict access for some routes and I try this:

```
app.use('/app/admin', function(req, res, next){
    AccessToken.findOne({ where: { id: req.cookies.Authorization}}, function(err, access_token){
        if(err || !access_token) return res.json({isAdmin: false});
        RoleMapping.findOne({ where: { principalId: access_token.user.id}}, function(err, role_mapping){
            role_mapping.user(function(err, user){
                if(err || !user) return res.json({isAdmin: false});
                // trying to check this user's static role
            });
            if(err || !role_mapping) return res.json({isAdmin: false});
            next();
        });
    })
});
```

but it's ended up crashed with this stack trace:

```
/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-explorer/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:134:22)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:246:10)
    at /Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/server/boot/routes.js:75:34
    at /Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1524:62
    at /Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1456:9
    at Object.async.each (/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:153:20)
    at allCb (/Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1394:13)
    at /Users/macbookair/node_project/microsite/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:729:9
```

How can I solve this error or are there any other ways to restrict access to particular routes?

Answer (score 2):

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. It appears you are trying to call `res.json` multiple times which must be in Head and becomes Finished.

You should look for anything that tries to send a header after part of the body has already been written.